# XSLT: How to get 'match' value in template to use it inside of the template

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<xsl:template match="email|recall|shop|partners|ipad" mode="tab">
  <li id="{HERE_MATCHED_PATH}">
  </li>
</xsl:template>
```

Is there any possibility to get matched path and use it in place of {HERE_MATCHED_PATH}?

For example to get something like this:

```
<li id="email">
</li>
```

if matched pattern was 'email'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `name()` or `local-name()`. In your case there is no difference as you are not dealing with namespace prefixes and both functions return the same value. For more information, see XPath functions reference.

Comment: That was fast and it works like a charm :D Even stackoverflow do not let me accept this answer so fast :D

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
<xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
```